# ffmpeg command to convert from mp4 video to .h264 raw frame with avcc format

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I want to convert my mp4 video (BigBuckBunny.mp4) to BigBuckBunny.h264 file. I used the following the command in ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i c:\BigBuckBunny.mp4 -c:v libx264 c:\Bunni2.h264
```

This command is able to convert the video to raw h264 file. When I opened the file in file viewer the NAL header preceded with 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 (4 bytes - start bytes).

But I want the frame to have size (avcc format) in little endian instead of start bytes. I am looking for output options to generate .h264 file in avcc format.

Comment: If you insist, you probably need to patch it by removing these lines: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n5.0/libavformat/rawenc.c#L347-L349

Comment: What exactly is the reason that you want to have such a raw stream though? Why is mp4 not acceptable to you?

Comment: By the way, suppressing the bsf is probably not enough unless you are using `-c:v copy` with an avcc input (probably the the case with an mp4). If you actually want to reencode it with libx264, you probably need to set the `annexb` x264 param to 0 *additionally*.

Answer (score 1):

Select `m4v` output format.

`m4v` format applies "MPEG-4 Part 2 video format", and applies H.264 with AVCC format (it's undocumented).

---

In case your original video is already encoded in H.264 codec, use `-vcodec copy -f m4v`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_1MB.mp4 -vcodec copy -f m4v Bunni2.h264
```

In case you have to re-encode the input, you may encode the input with FLV container  and use pipe to second FFmpeg with `-vcodec copy -f m4v`:

```
ffmpeg -i Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_1MB.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -f flv pipe: | ffmpeg -y -i pipe: -vcodec copy -f m4v Bunni2.h264
```

Comment: Ah, looks like many of the raw muxers are generic...so one can just cheat it with `m4v` or even `m2v`...